# Are the friendly links to question always valid no matter how much time the title has changed?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, permalink

I've noted that after the title of the question is edited, so change the friendly link, but the old friendly link is still valid and results in redirection to the new link.

According to the question [Are friendly links to SO questions permanent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92283/are-friendly-links-to-so-questions-permanent) friendly links are permantent, however, the question has not mentioned title change.

So, I'd like to know for sure, and precise that question? If the question title changes a few times, will ALL the friendly links related to the question stay valid forever (well, let's say, as long as the question itself exists), or there is some limit or the time the old link is still valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title part of the URL is completely optional, you can supply anything there and it will still link to the correct post, as long as the ID is correct.

As an example, follow this URL:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136373/are-unicorns-better-than-waffles
```

In short, title changes will never invalidate a URL.

Comment: Oh, so easy to implement and no performance impact. Why I haven't thought about it?

Comment: But, just as an aside: using a different URL *will* require an additional HTTP request [for the 301 Moved Permanently response](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F136373%2Fare-unicorns-better-than-waffles&http=1.1&type=GET&uak=0). Hence, a little performance impact, @lechlukasz.